# Stop redirecting on aliasmatch

Tags: apache, redirect, alias

Using Apache conf, on my site I want to load different document root for some urls.

For example:

```
www.example.com/abc
www.example.com/abc/def
www.example.com/abc/def/ghi
```

I want to load document root /var/www/something_else for /abc and all other urls following /abc/

I have tried with

```
Alias /abc /var/www/something_else
```

It only works for the URL /abc, but if I use

```
AliasMatch ^/abc/(.*)$ /var/www/something_else
```

It gives me redirect loop "This webpage has a redirect loop"